# How to move tree item into other tree item with no children in angular material with drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, tree, drag-and-drop

I have flattened tree with checkboxes.

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource"
      [treeControl]="treeControl"
      cdkDropList
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
<mat-tree-node
        *matTreeNodeDef="let node"
        matTreeNodePadding
        cdkDrag
        [cdkDragData]="node"
        (mouseenter)="dragHover(node)"
        (mouseleave)="dragHoverEnd()"
        (cdkDragStarted)="dragStart()"
        (cdkDragReleased)="dragEnd()"
        [disabled]="!node.enabled">
    <mat-checkbox [checked]="node.enabled"
                  (change)="node.enabled = $event.checked"
                  [disabled]="node.system">
    </mat-checkbox>
    <mat-icon>{{node.icon || 'no_sim'}}</mat-icon>&nbsp;<span>{{node.title || node.name}}</span>
    <button
            *ngIf="node.expandable"
            mat-icon-button
            (click)="expansionModel.toggle(node.name)"
            matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
        <mat-icon>
            {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more'}}
        </mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="edit(node)" title="{{'Edit' | translate}}">
        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="node.custom" (click)="remove(node)" title="{{'Remove' | translate}}">
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-tree-node>
```

Other code is like here https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tree-with-drag-and-drop?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts

Is there a way to add one item into other with no children? I can move item into other item with children...

Can think about on event `dragHover` check if item has children. If not, add some temp item, move dragged item into it and delete temp item. But as I'm working with flat items... not sure if this is good solution. It's just an idea